# knitr -- ! LaTeX Error: File `figure/unnamed-chunk-1' not found

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm new to knitr and to Latex.

I keep getting the error "! LaTeX Error: File `figure/unnamed-chunk-1' not found." The error message says:

```
>! LaTeX Error: File `figure/unnamed-chunk-1' not found.
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
> l.77 ...[width=\textwidth]{figure/unnamed-chunk-1}
> I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
> .png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps
```

I have a simple tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\author{My Name }
\title{knitr example}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

<<loading,echo=F>>=
library(ggplot2)
@

<< message=F,fig.width=9,fig.height=6,out.width='\\textwidth',cache= TRUE>>=
mydata  <- data.frame(year = seq(1901: 1950), debt = rnorm(50))
plot(mydata$year, mydata$debt, main = "Debt")
@
\end{document}
```

I cannot seem to locate anything that seems relevant. Clearly "figure/unnamed-chunk-1" should be showing up somewhere but I don't see anything in the knitr options document to suggest a specific way to save it and so far I don't understand enough about knitr to figure out a way to name a plot to be imported.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Can you paste `sessionInfo()` after `library(knitr)`? Are all packages up-to-date? The only possible reason I can think of is that you ran it once before but deleted the `figure` directory later; since this chunk was cached, the plot will not be re-generated unless anything is changed. Does it work if you remove the option `cache=TRUE`?

Answer (score 1):

It has been solved in the [knitr mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/knitr/browse_thread/thread/fecc38b00b4b9284). The problem was due to use of absolute paths in the `output` argument in `knit()`, so figures and tex output were not in the same directory. It is not recommended to use absolute paths in general; see more discussion in the mailing list.

Comment: I'm having the samme issue, but unfortunately have not been able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but it I stumbled the issues recently, whether on MacOS or Win. I have tried the solution above but didn't work. What works for me is to delete all the figure inside `figure-latex` folder and re-run the knit.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I tried this, but unfortunately it did not resolve the issue for me.